# Auth Context not allowing protected routes to be accessed after Firebase Auth sign-in within React web app

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am building a React web app with Firebase Auth, within which I want to protect certain routes depending upon whether a User is signed in or not.

To do this, I am using Context to build a AuthProvider / AuthContext, creating a 'PrivateRoute' based off of this context and whether the User is signed in, before wrapping the protected routes in the newly created PrivateRoute within my App.js.

The routes are now protected, and attempting to access them redirects me to my sign-in page.

Upon signing in though, the sign-in submits successfully, and a token is generated and stored in local storage. However, the protected routes still can't be accessed.

I suspect this is to do with the structure of my App.js file, but can't be totally sure.

Here's my code..

Auth.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';

export const AuthContext  = React.createContext();

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const  [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setCurrentUser);
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{currentUser}}
        >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

PrivateRoute.js - noting the console log returns undefined...

```
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { AuthContext } from './Auth'
    
    export default function PrivateRoute({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) {
        let currentUser = useContext(AuthContext)
        console.log(currentUser)
        return (
            <Route
            {...rest}
            render={routeProps =>
            !!currentUser ? (
                <RouteComponent {...routeProps} currentUser={currentUser} />
            ) : (
                <Redirect to={'/sign-in'}/>
            )
            }
            />
        )
    }
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import './App.css';
import './nodes.css'
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';


import Homepage from './components/index/homepage';
import SignIn from './components/sign-in/sign-in';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/dashboard';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      <Switch>

      <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage}  />
      <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />

      </Switch>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I've not included any of my component code within this question, but if it would help to answer this question I'm more than happy to add it.

Thanks!

EDIT: My sign-in component..

```
class SignIn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    }
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }

  onSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then((response) => {

      let user = firebase.auth().currentUser

      if (user.emailVerified === false) {
        this.props.history.push("/sign-in")
        firebase.auth().signOut()
        alert("You need to verify your email first.")
      } else {
        this.props.history.push("/dashboard")
      }

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
      });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="signin-section">
        <div className="signin-container">

          <form className="signin-form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <label className="signin-form-label">Email</label>
            <input className="signin-form-input" type="email" name="email" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.email}/>
            <label className="signin-form-label">Password</label>
            <input className="signin-form-input" type="password" name="password" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.password} />
            <button className="signin-form-button" type="submit" name="button">Continue</button>
            <a className="signin-form-reset" href="reset">Forgotten your password?</a>
            <a className="signin-register-link" href="register">Not got an account? Sign up.</a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default SignIn;
```

My

Comment: Have you try to `console.log(currentUser)` to see if it is not null or not undefined? Can you show your login logic code?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added a console.log to my PrivateRoute file before the return, and it's returning undefined... So assume that's partly the problem? I'll update my answer with my login component too.

Comment: How do you use your `AuthProvider`?  I see you create and share context in your `AuthProvider` to children but I don't see any related children of `AuthProvider`

Comment: I suggest to define context in App level so that you can access your context through all components

Comment: Can you provide an answer explaining this with examples? I have tried adding 'AuthProvider' to both my index.js and App.js, wrapping my components in the 'AuthProvider', but it doesn't work. The 'auth' goes and I can access my routes without signing in.